# Maximum recursion depth error when using ModelCheckpoint in Keras

Tags: keras

I'm training a model with ~30,000 parameters, and I would like to use the ModelCheckpoint callback to save the state of the model after each epoch.

Currently, I cannot save the model. I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I tried a solution that I found elsewhere (e.g. [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2489)) but it doesn't help.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I found a clue [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12081)...

...and modified it. I have a Lambda layer that was originally written like this:

```
    def sampling(args):
        z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
        epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=((self.batch_size - self.n_lags), self.hid_dim_2), mean=0., stddev=1.) 
        return z_mean + z_log_sigma * epsilon

    zlambda = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(self.hid_dim_2,))([z_mean, z_log_sigma])
```

I moved the `shape` to a global variable, and voila!

```
    shape_val = ((self.batch_size - self.n_lags), self.hid_dim_2) #Need this to be a global variable, otherwise Recursion Depth Error of death.

    def sampling(args):
        z_mean, z_log_sigma = args
        epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=shape_val, mean=0., stddev=1.)
        return z_mean + z_log_sigma * epsilon

    zlambda = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(self.hid_dim_2,))([z_mean, z_log_sigma]) #Saving and loading Lambda layers is weird.
```